# Downloading only new subtitles in RaspberyPi

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have problems with writing downloading subtitles on Raspberry Pi with bash script.

The issue is I would like to have 1 script running with cron every hour or so that would download subtitles for new video files in some directory.

There is a program called qnapi that automatically downloads subtitles in the correct format in the directory but it works for 1 folder and always re-downloads subtitle files.

usage is:

```
qnapi /path/to/folder
```

So what I've found is

```
find /media/pi/RaspStorage -iname "*.mkv"
```

basically gives me a list of all movie files. Now I would like to somehow compare if a *.srt subtitle file with a same base name exists and if no then somehow loop through all found files with qnapi command. Write it in a bash script and cron it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for help :)

I got it working

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Updated DLNA folder"

sudo minidlnad -R

for file in $(find /media/pi/RaspStorage -name '*.mkv' -or -name '*.avi'); do
 name=${file:: -4}
 ext=".srt"
 name=$name$ext

 if [ -f $name ]; then
  echo "Napisy już ściągnięte dla:" "$(basename "$file")"
 else
 qnapi "$(dirname "$file")"/"$(basename "$file")"
 fi
done
```

Works fine. All subtitles are downloading and if there are some already it's skipping

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along the line of this would work (untested, may have typos).

I'm guessing at the syntax of `qnapi` from a google search.

Basically, symlink videos that don't have subtitles into a temporary folder, download the subtitles there, then move them back to the main folder.

```
#!/bin/bash

MEDIA=/media/pi/RaspStorage
WORK=/tmp/workingfolder
mkdir -p "$WORK"
pushd "$WORK" || { echo "ERROR: no working directory"; exit 1; }
# assuming subtitle name is video name except with ".srt" extension
find "$MEDIA" -iname "*.mkv" | while read video; do
    vidnoext="${video%????}"
    viddir="${vidnoext%/*}"
    subtitle="${vidnoext}.srt"
    if [ ! -f "$subtitle" ]; then
        # this assumes bare filenames (without directory) are distinct
        ln -s "$video" "${vidnoext}.mkv"
    fi
done
qnapi -c .
find . -iname '*.srt' | while IFS= read -r subtitle; do
    video="$(realpath "$(subtitle%????}.mkv")"
    mv -i "$subtitle" "$(dirname "$video")/"
done
rm *
popd
rmdir "$WORK"
```